# Cómo validar si existe una tabla y registros?

Tags: php

Estoy validando que existan registros o no en una tabla, pero también quiero validar si existe la tabla. Hice esto:

```
<?php
$conexion = new ConexionDB();    
$sql = "SELECT codigo, fecha FROM tabla";
if ($stm = $conexion->query($sql)){
    if ($stm->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "Tabla tiene registros";
    } else {
        echo "Tabla no tiene registros";
    }
} else {
    echo "Problemas de Conexión";
}
?>
```

Estoy usando `PHP/PDO`.
Pero me arroja error en la línea del `If`, cuando la tabla no existe:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146

Answer (score 1):

La consulta

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table'
```

Debería devolverte 1 fila si existe.

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

La consulta

```
$result = mysql_query("DESCRIBE 'myTable'");
if ($result) 
{
  $sql = "SELECT codigo, fecha FROM myTable";
  if ($stm = $conexion->query($sql))
  {
     if ($stm->rowCount() > 0) 
     {
      echo "Tabla tiene registros";
     } 
     else 
     {
      echo "Tabla no tiene registros";
     }
  }     
}
 else 
 {
  echo "Esta tabla no existe"
 }
```

Debería devolverte 1 si existe.

Espero te sirva

Comment: Es que estoy haciendo las pruebas, y la tabla no existe. Entonces al no existir debería ejecutar el else del If. Pero no lo hace. Estoy usando PDO.

Comment: SELECT codigo, fecha FROM tabla

Esa consulta va a devolver error, primero deberías tirar la de alguna de las 2 respuestas, y entonces hacer el if else

Comment: listo he editado mi respuesta

Comment: Pero yo estoy utilizando PHP/PDO por eso tengo ese problema. Y según el manual de PHP el mysql_query está deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que es MySQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'yourdb' 
    AND table_name = 'testtable'
LIMIT 1;
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/check-if-table-exists-without-using-select-from